# Codeigniter insert id model using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How can I get the value of the productid in the php code?

```
function getunitstock(){
    var productid = document.getElementById('product').value

    <?php $prodbyid = $this->pos_model->get_productbyid(+productid+)?> 

    document.getElementById('unitprice').value = <?php echo $prodbyid['price'];?>
}
```

Comment: you cannot get direct value from js in php.. instead of this call ajax to getprodbyid value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use javascript variable in php code. Php code run's on the serverside and javascript code runs in the client side. You can't ask the browser to run php code.

```
<?php $prodbyid = $this->pos_model->get_productbyid(+productid+)?>'
```

So, this line won't get value of productid.

The only way to do what you are looking to do is either:

- do a redirect to a PHP script or do an AJAX call to a PHP script